# How to play AudioWorkletNode from disk

Tags: cordova, phonegap, web-audio-api

At the [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) page is mentioned:

> To play sounds which require accurate timing but must be streamed from the network or played from disk, use a AudioWorkletNode to implement its playback.

but I'm not sure how do I do that in the context of a mobile app development (Phonegap/Cordova based).

It is kind of an audio mixer, where the user specifies the audio files he wants to play (the files must be kept in sync).

Any good hearted person could give me a hint?

Thanks.